# Limit points and Homeomorphism

Tags: real-analysis, gn.general-topology, limits-and-convergence

I was asking this question at [Mathematics SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4128343/translating-limit-point-under-homeomorphism-map) but I got nothing at all. This is why I am trying this site.

We consider the topology of the extended real line. Let $h\colon [-\infty,\infty]\to\Bbb R$ and suppose $(-\infty,0)$ and $(\infty,0)$ are limit point of the graph of $h$, that is, they are limit points of $\{(x,h(x))\colon x\in\Bbb R\}$.  Now, let $g\colon (a,b)\to \Bbb R$ be a homeomorphism. Notice that $\lim\limits_{x \to a^{+}}g(x)=\infty$ or $-\infty$ and $\lim\limits_{x \to b^{-}}g(x)=\infty$ or $-\infty$. This is true for any homeomorphism.  Now, consider $h\circ g\colon (a,b)\to \Bbb R$.

**Claim**: $(a,0)$ and $(b,0)$ are limit points of the graph of $h\circ g$.
I think my claim would be true since homemomorphism behaves nicely with topological property.

My attempt was to consider a  sequence $x_n$ in $(a,b)$ and show $(x_n, (h\circ g)(x_n))\to (a,0)$ but I could not finish. Maybe I should start direct with definition of limit points.  This is why I am asking. Any help will be appreciated greatly.

Comment: Link to the post at m.se?

Comment: @GerryMyerson, did you mean should I add the link

Comment: @00GB, yes, you should.  Presumably it's https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4128343/translating-limit-point-under-homeomorphism-map ?

Comment: @LSpice, HERE IS THE LINK https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4128343/707884

Comment: So, it seems you waited one day to post here. It's recommended to wait a week. Also, please edit a link to this question into the m.se question.

Comment: @LSpice, Thank you for edit the question

Comment: @GerryMyerson, from what I know if the question has no answer (even comment) for day or two. Most likely will not get any thing.. Thank you

Comment: https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/3457/if-i-cant-get-an-answer-on-math-stackexchange-com-or-dsp-stackexchange-com-whe and https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/2637/cross-posts-to-math-se

Comment: By the way, no need any more to link here from there, I did it for you.

Comment: @GerryMyerson, Thank you, I did not know the rule.

Comment: Isn't this just a matter of inserting things into the definitions? Let's say that $g$ is increasing. There are $y_n\to -\infty$ such that $h(y_n)\to 0$. Write $y_n=g(x_n)$. Then $x_n\to a$ since $g$ is a homeomorphism, and $(h\circ g)(x_n)\to 0$.

Comment: Dirk Werner ,Thank you . Did you assume $g$ increasing is it because g is homeomorphism? Right ? You used the sequence instead of direct definition of limit point . Right

Comment: Yes, a homeomorphism on an interval is increasing or decreasing; wlog I assumed it to be increasing.

Comment: @DirkWerner, Okay. Thank you. since you answered the question. It would be good to add it as answer instead of comment it  would be useful for others as well.

Comment: @00GB: Thanks, I'll do.

Comment: @DirkWerner, one more little thing  to make sure I got it your solution. why $x_n\to a.$

Comment: @DirkWerner, Is it because $g$ is increasing from the assumption ?

Comment: Sure.   (Comments have to be 15 characters in length. Here you are.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A homeomorphism on an interval is increasing or decreasing; wlog I assume it to be increasing. There are $y_n \to -\infty$ such that $h(y_n)\to 0$. Write $y_n=g(x_n)$. Then $x_n = g^{-1}(g(x_n)) \to a$ since $g$ is a homeomorphism and $y_n\to -\infty$, and $(h\circ g)(x_n)\to 0$.